# Using the capture operator in an umbrella app - elixir

Tags: elixir

I have an umbrella app,
which in one app(ex: App1) i am sending a function as an argument to a different function located in another app(ex: App2).
I am sending the function like this:

```
defmodule App1.Bar do
  def bar_bar(fun) do
    fun.()
  end
end

defmodule App2.Foo do
  def foo_foo do
    App1.Bar.bar_bar(&Io.puts(Project.get.project[:app]))
  end
end
```

My question is:
does that function actually executed in `App1` or in `App2`(where it's being defined)?

Comment: It's propably typo, because you call `App2.Bar`'s function not from `App1.Bar`.

Comment: @PatNowak, thanks,edited

Answer (score 2):

If you were to do something like this, it will be **executed** in `App1`, but it will be **evaluated** in `App2`.

Lets take a look at what this actually means. Assume we have the following modules:

```
defmodule Foo do
  def foo(fun) do
    IO.puts "I AM IN FOO"
    fun.()
  end
end
defmodule Bar do
  def bar(), do: Foo.foo(fn -> IO.inspect baz() end)
  defp baz(), do: "baz"
end

iex(1)> Bar.bar()
I AM IN FOO
"baz"
"baz"
```

The two important parts to note here are:

- We printed `I AM IN FOO` before we see the print in our anonymous function. Which means the function is executed in `Foo`.
- We were able to evaluate `Bar.baz/0`, even though `Foo` is unable to see that function (it also doesn't have a `baz/0` function of its own). Which means it must have been evaluated BEFORE being passed to `Foo.foo/1`.

Answer (score 1):

This example will throw CompileError, because Capture operator assumes that you will provide function, which would looks like:

```
&Mod.fun/arity
&local/arity
```

or at least you will specify one argument for that using also Capture operator eg. `&Mod.fun(&1)`.

In this case your argument is wrong.
Without Capture operator and using regular way of making anonymous functions you would have there:

```
fn -> Io.puts(Project.get.project[:app]) end
```

So it will work for the content of `Project.get.project[:app]`. I'm not familiar with that fancy module, but it should work in the very module you called it.

Comment: when i do it as u suggested fn -> Io.puts(Project.get.project[:app]) end , which will be the app running?

Comment: The one that runs this function - App2.

Answer (score 1):

To control the Project that a function is executed in, you can use [Mix.Project.in_project/4](https://hexdocs.pm/mix/Mix.Project.html#in_project/4)

```
Mix.Project.in_project :my_app, "/path/to/my_app", fn module ->
  "Mixfile is: #{inspect module}"
end
#=> "Mixfile is: MyApp.Mixfile"
```

In general passing lambdas between functions will preserve the lexical scope from where the lambda was defined.

However passing lambdas between *processes* will cause `self()` to evaluate to a different value:

```
iex(10)> lambda = fn -> IO.puts("Lambda running in: #{inspect(self())}") end
#Function<20.52032458/0 in :erl_eval.expr/5>

iex(11)> lambda.()
Lambda running in: #PID<0.80.0>
:ok

iex(12)> spawn(lambda)
Lambda running in: #PID<0.96.0>
#PID<0.96.0>
```

This can change the output of anything that relies on the current Process dictionary, such as `Ecto.Repo` which stores the current connection in the Process dictionary when inside a transaction.